# android studio intent inside intent crash

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

So I have two activities, let's call them A and B, activity A have a text input and a button, which call to activity B with an intent method:

and I have activity B which have also intent to the camera application:

```
ImageView photo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.b);

    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

    Button buttonCapture = findViewById(R.id.buttonCapture);
    photo = findViewById(R.id.photo);

    buttonCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent1, 0);
        }
    });
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) (data != null ? requireNonNull(data.getExtras()).get("data") : null);
    photo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

and when I launch this in a simulator, I get the first A activity fine, click on the button, it open activity B, I press the button again, and it returns me to activity A or crash(random?)
my manifest file:

```
package="com.example.user.app">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".A">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".B">
    </activity>

</application>
```

with the exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.user.app, PID: 18441
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE cmp=com.android.camera2/com.android.camera.CaptureActivity } from ProcessRecord{296747c 18441:com.example.user.app/u0a88} (pid=18441, uid=10088) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA
```

Comment: Post your exception also.

Comment: i added manifest and the exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I see...

Starting Android 6 (API 23), if your app has CAMERA permission declared in the manifest, it needs that CAMERA permission to be **GRANTED** in order to access ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE etc... too (which normally do not require the CAMERA permission on their own). If not, then it automatically raises a SecurityException.

do like below!!!

1- If you only need ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE etc..

Remove the CAMERA permission from manifest and you would be fine

2- If you need CAMERA permission too

Check for CAMERA permission at runtime and only start the intent when the permission is available

Comment: How do i check permission in run time?

Answer (score 0):

1) it maybe happens when you don't declare your B activity in manifests!!!

2)remove final before defining EditText and try again!!!

if you send your logs, I can help you better...

Comment: i added my manifest, if i try to remove the final it give me an error, but also i even tried without the edittext at all, it still crashes